# @ParameterizedTest not working with parameters

Tags: java, junit, azure-functions

I'm creating test cases for an Azure Function. I'd like to use parameterized tests but it refuses to pick up any test that has parameters. I used the official Azure Functions Maven archetype to generate the project. Here's the relevant parts from the POM (NOTE: I put in the exclusion to make sure I wasn't accidentally loading in junit4 (didn't change anything), and there is no specific surefire-plugin configuration section in my POM).

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
                    <resourceGroup>example</resourceGroup>
                    <appServicePlanName>example</appServicePlanName>
                    <region>example</region>
                    <!-- <pricingTier></pricingTier> -->
                    <!-- <disableAppInsights></disableAppInsights> -->
                    <runtime>
                        <!-- runtime os, could be windows, linux or docker-->
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <javaVersion>11</javaVersion>
                    </runtime>
                    <appSettings>
                        <property>
                            <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                            <value>~4</value>
                        </property>
                    </appSettings>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-functions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

and here's the test code:

```java
public class FunctionTest {
    @Test
    public void testTrue() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = {"example"})
    public void testNoParams() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = {"example"})
    public void testOneParam(String string) {
        assertEquals(string, "example");
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource
    public void testExtractSiteKeyShouldReturnMatchingGroup(String input, String output) throws Exception {
        Function function = new Function();
        assertEquals(function.extractSiteKey(Logger.getGlobal(), input), output);
    }

    private static Stream<Arguments> testExtractSiteKeyShouldReturnMatchingGroup() {
        return Stream.of(
            Arguments.of(null, null),
            Arguments.of("", null),
            Arguments.of(" ", null),
            Arguments.of("notmatching", null),
        );
    }
}
```

The only two tests that are picked up are, which are the two that don't have parameters:

```xml
  <testcase classname="com.example.FunctionTest" name="com.example.FunctionTest.testNoParams" time="0.001"/>
  <testcase classname="com.example.FunctionTest" name="com.example.FunctionTest.testTrue" time="0"/>
```

As some additional information, it also refuses to pick up the test cases that aren't prefixed with "test", e.g. testOneParam works, oneParam doesn't.

Comment: don't you have to specify the name of the method in `@MethodSource`? ie
`@MethodSource("testExtractSiteKeyShouldReturnMatchingGroup")`

Comment: apparently not, says https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5#6-method, but I've tried it with the method name as well and still doesn't work. And that still wouldn't explain the testOneParam example :S

Comment: Why did you you use  ValueSource annotation for test without arguments? I  mean for testNoParam method.

Comment: @AnatoliiChub to test whether it wasn't getting picked up because of an error in the parameter source or in the function signature. The fact that it does work with ValueSource but no parameter (testNoParam) but not in testOneParam suggests it's something to do with the signature itself perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was fixed by explicitly adding in the maven-surefire plugin version above 2.22.2:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
</plugin>
```

The one provided out of the box is version 2.12.4 (apparently it only picks up @ParameterTest annotations as of junit 5.5.1 and surefire-plugin version 2.22.2)